# axis2 set custom headers on Mime part

Tags: wso2, apache-axis

I'm using axis2 to send an attachment. I'm creating a ConfigurableDataHandler. Below is a snippet of my code:

`dataHandler.setTransferEncoding(transferEncoding);
dataHandler.setContentType(contentType)enter code here;
axis2MsgContext.addAttachment(contentId, dataHandler);`

I want to set content-disposition mime header and some custom mime header on the mime part.
How should I proceed.

Answer (score 0):

Got it.
I extended ConfigurableDataHandler to keep a map of attachment headers.
Then I created my own messageFormatter implementation by extending org.apache.axis2.transport.MessageFormatter

and in the writeTo method, created a OMMultipartWriter object. 
 attachmentsWriter = new OMMultipartWriter(innerOutputStream, innerFormat);
and then called 
attachmentsWriter.writePart(myDataHandler, contentID,myDataHandler.getExtraHeaders());